# Bind a function with dynamic arguments to Highcharts point

Tags: jquery, events, binding, highcharts

I want to bind a function to a click event for a data point in Highcharts. Clicking a data point has to call a function, but the arguments to the function are dynamic (i.e. there are several graphs drawn, and the "car" variable is generated anew for each graph).

How to bind "getCarDate()" to click event properly? This does not work (car simply holds the last assigned value instead of a different value for each plot):

```
                         plotOptions: {
                            series: {
                                cursor: 'pointer',
                                point: {
                                    events: {
                                        click: function (e) {
                                            getCarDate(this.x, car)
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                marker: {
                                    lineWidth: 1
                                }
                            }
                        },
```

Comment: this seems to be working what is the issue?

Comment: It does not work as expected. As I wrote, when rendering several such charts in a loop, the click event gets the car value of the chart _rendered as the last_. E.g. chart 1 has car "Mazda", chart 2 has car "Toyota", chart 3 has car "Hyundai". When clicking a data point with function assigned as above, the getCarDate function always gets the "car" variable from last drawn chart, i.e. "Hyundai", regardless of which chart we click.

Comment: if you are able to produce the scenario in http://jsfiddle.net then that would be great to help.

Comment: There: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=4FUsPTknG6 

Whenever you click a data point in any chart, you get "Hyundai". I want the correct car :). I know what the _root_ of the problem is (the variable is passed to the function at binding time, not execution time). I just don't know the proper syntax to make passing of the variable dynamic (at runtime).

Comment: @dust, your fiddle link doesn't work

Comment: OK, I shared a wrong link. Even though you actually solved the problem below already, here is the original fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JUfS7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick you could use here would be to stash the value into the Highcharts options:

```
$('#container'+i).highcharts({

    myData: car,

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point:{                 
                events: {
                    click: function(event) {     
                       alert(this.series.chart.userOptions.myData);
                    }
                }
           }
        }
    },
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C4R3M/).

Comment: Mark, thank you -- a very neat trick. I actually "solved" the issue in a similar way, by stashing the value in an "onmouseover" event for the given chart's wrapping <div>. Your solution, even though still a workaround, is much neater.